# phpStorm не видит пути к файлу на ftp

Tags: php, phpstorm, ftp

Прописываю пути к файлам в коде, например

```
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png"/>
```

Подсвечивает icon, и пишет cannot resolve file "icon.png"

Так же после например такого кода

```
require_once 'filename.php';
```

он пишет path 'filename.php'not found

Оба файла существуют, все редактируется, сохраняется, отображается на домене без ошибок, но подсвечивает ошибку во время редактирования, и из за этого функиця Go To совершенно недоступна, да и визуально внимание уходит на несуществующие ошибки, надоело уже.

Как это исправить? Интересует именно на ftp, не на локалке.

Comment: Что значит на фтп? т.е. вы с фтп вытаскиваете один файл, запихиваете в редактор и удивляетесь почему он выдает вам там ошибки?

Comment: Со шторма редактирую весь проект на фтп целиком. Ну, чтоб вам проще было, папки там, файлы разные. И когда я в коде обращаюсь к файлу, который тоже лежит в проекте, мне шторм говорит что не видит его. Хотя код запускается, и файлы на самом деле он видит.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте новый проект, выбкрите на первой странице что проект находится на FTP. Пройдите все последующие пути и дождитесь загрузки проекта. Вуаля, теперь у вас папка с проектом локально которую вы можете деплоить обратно на ftp и все пути будут рабочими.

Comment: Именно так я и создавал. мне шторм показывает весь проект, но видимо нет локальной копии, поэтому после например require_once, я могу использовать переменные из файла, но не могу сделать Go to -> Declaration, хотя очень хотелось бы.
как добавить локальную копию?